# ASP.NET Elimination of webuser controls with same inside controls ID

Tags: asp.net, client-side, webusercontrol

I want to remove some web user controls with same client side ID of the asp controls that are inside.

here a short example

HTML of Web User Control, Control Name is "**home**"

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runar="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" />
```

Now usage of this web user control

```
<uc1:Home runat="server" ID="Home" />
```

Rendered client IDs of inside webuser controls are,

```
Home_lblStatus
Home_btnSubmit
```

Now here is my question,
I want to remove user control with same client side IDs.
Anybody have any idea for this?

**Note**
I'am not using any master page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could not find same client side id in the question?

Comment: Do you mean - your page will contain more than one <uc1:Home /> usercontrol ? Your requirement is not very clear, sorry

Comment: Actually I have used too many Jqury with client IDs and now i want to eliminate the web user controls.
but when i do this, control Ids changes

**Home_btnSubmit to btnSubmit**
But I want to use same ID with eliminate the web user control.

Thanks for your response.